# How to pass parameters to sh file with php?

Tags: php, shell, variables, exec

I'm executing this command:

```
exec('sh myFile.sh paramater1')
```

But in `myFile.sh`, how to get `parameter1`?

I didn't find any information about it

Comment: That will be  accessed as `$1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command line parameters in shell are referenced as `$1`, `$2`, and so forth.

As a side note:

- $0 is the name of the command
- $# is the total number of parameters
- $@ is all of the parameters